# Parsing code with JavaScript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, split

I am trying to pull information from a String.

```
%B6009050000000000^LASTNAME/FIRST MIDDLE^0000000A39418598900000000000000?;6009050000000000=00000000139418598900?
```

The information I need is `A39418598`.

I have assigned this to `var str` and now I need to split it and pass it to Ajax as `var id`.

**Do I use `var id = str.split('');`?** If so, how do I tell JavaScript exactly what I need? The rest of the data can be dismissed.

Comment: what is generating this string? if there is no defined format, then it will not be possible to programatically extract a certain piece of the string.

Comment: It's being defined by a card reader. The card is swiped, and that's the string that it presents. The A through 8 number will change but everything else will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
var s = "%B6009050000000000^LASTNAME/FIRST MIDDLE ^0000000A394185989000...";

s.match(/\^0+?([^0]+)/)[1];  //"A394185989"
```

this do the job, but be aware that this regexp is really specific for that string.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var str="%B6009050000000000^LASTNAME/FIRST MIDDLE";
 str=str+"^0000000A39418598900000000000000?;6009050000000000=00000000139418598900?" 

 str.match(/\^0+?([^0]+)/)[1];
```

Comment: nice, I would not have been able to propose a better regexp... :)

Comment: What an accident (there was no answer posted when I opened the question page).